# ExtJS json store not populating

Tags: json, extjs

I've recently taken a dive into ExtJS by inheriting a web app written in 3.4.  I've managed to create a store attached to a grid with no problem and have been able to bring up a PanelForm with data loaded from a call to a php page.

I have another json store defined which doesn't get populated when I call its load procedure and I'm wondering what I am missing.

The definition of the store is below:

```
var ImgStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
 totalProperty: 'total'
,root: 'data'
,url : 'json/getProductImage/'        
,fields : [{
    name : 'img'
},{
    name : 'extn'
}]
});
```

My code to load the data is:

```
ImgStore.load({callback: function() {}            
        ,params: {'ProductGUID': x}
    });
```

The code behind the URL is fine and the response in Firebug below:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"img":"iVBORw0KG...ggg==","extn":"png"}}
```

What I cannot understand is why the response comes back but the Store does not populate. I must be missing something; I just can't see what...

Does the Store have to be bound to another object? What I wanted to do was to read back the base64 encoded string and then show the image on screen (on either a panel, FormPanel or Container; not really sure of the best method really)

Any advice is greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

Your store needs a model. The model needs to reflect the attributes that are then being returned in your JSON feed. Only then will the data show up in your store.

Comment: there is no need for model on 3.4 http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-cfg-reader

Comment: as per above comment - I didn't think that one was needed as if not explicitly defined if created on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, except for the url config aren't u missing the name of the file ? `'json/getProductImage/myfile.json'`?

How are you validating store is not loaded by binding it to a grid? Because if so, store could be loading but not configuring grid properly might make u think store is not loaded, try `console.log(store.getTotalCount())`

Comment: no - this is a directory which contains an index.php file.  Index.php is set as the default document so gets read and fired on going to the folder.  I have 25 other examples of this working without issue so I don't believe that to be the case.  Regards to validation - I had used console.log(ImgStore) which returned an empty object.  Same call to another JsonStore which is populated with data returns the object which can then be browsed.  I'm not binding it to a grid; my point is that one created which is bound to a grid is working, this is not yet the methods are identical.

Comment: take into account js is asynchronous, so if you do store.load() and after that console.log() store might still be loading

Comment: so by the time you console.log it is still empty, and would be a good practice putting the name of the file in url. Put ImgStore.getTotalCount() inside callback function.

Comment: `ImgStore.getTotalCount()` doesn't fire in the callback... Also - I've added a success and failure handler just with a `console.log` but it doesn't fire either.  Strange though that that is the only place on the page which calls this php file and it does get fired if I put a break point in firebug and stepped over the code.  something isn't right

Comment: should really consider adding index.php to url